# How can I use something similar to Offset.Select and Set Selection without using it?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2.  Each cell I'm copying from Sheet1 needs to be pasted 9 times to Sheet2.  So it would look something like this.

**Sheet1**

| - | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Date/Time |
| 2 | 3/3/21 00:00 |

**Sheet2**

| - | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Date/Time |
| 2 | 3/3/21 00:00 |
| 3 | 3/3/21 00:00 |
| 4 | 3/3/21 00:00 |
| 5 | 3/3/21 00:00 |
| 6 | 3/3/21 00:00 |
| 7 | 3/3/21 00:00 |
| 8 | 3/3/21 00:00 |
| 9 | 3/3/21 00:00 |
| 10 | 3/3/21 00:00 |

I'm trying to follow better practices than what I would normally do, but I'm unable to find a way to avoid using Select.

Here's the current version of my code.  And writing it out I just realized I forgot to declare one of my range variables.

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim dat as Variant
Dim rng As range
Dim i As Long
Dim i2 As Long

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A2:A96815")
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").range("A2:A871336")

dat = rng

    For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
        rng2.Value = dat(i, 1)
        rng2.Offset(9, 0).Select
        Set rng2 = Selection
    Next i
End Sub
```

I have it running right now but it's going to take a very long time to finish and I don't think it will actually work.

How could I improve it so I don't need to use Offset.Select and Set my range selection every time it loops?  Can i define the Cells within the range that are being used with a variable and changing those every loop?

Comment: Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(9, 0) ;
value = rng2.Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i had to do this, I'd do it like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    
    'Use with Block to refer to sheet1 without writting the path
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        'find the last row with data
        Dim i As Long: i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'input the whole range into an array
        Dim dat As Variant: dat = .Range("A2:A" & i).Value
    End With
    'resize another array equal to dat * 9 times (as you need each cell 9 times)
    ReDim dest(1 To UBound(dat) * 9, 1 To 1) As Variant
    'start a count variable with value 1
    Dim x As Long: x = 1
    Dim y As Long
    'loop through the dat array to fill the dest array
    For i = 1 To UBound(dat)
        'for each value in dat, input 9 times into dest
        For y = 1 To 9
            dest(x, 1) = dat(i, 1)
            x = x + 1
        Next y
    Next i
    'find the first row without data in sheet2 and paste the dest array
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A" & i).Resize(UBound(dest), UBound(dest, 2)).Value = dest
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a great solution, I didn't think about copying from one array to another and then pasting the array.  Awesome solution and it took a matter of seconds thank you!